# Upper limit of a measure sequence example

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E_n$ a sequence in a $\sigma$-algebra
$\limsup \mu(E_n)\leq \mu (\limsup E_n) $ when $\mu(\bigcup E_n)<+\infty$. 
what happen when $\mu(\bigcup E_n)=+\infty$? I need an example

Comment: Note on the terminology: usually we say *upper limit* or *limit superior*.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the claim will not hold then. Consider on $\mathbf R$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the Lebesgue measure, the sets 
$$ E_n = [n, \infty) $$
Then $\limsup E_n = \emptyset$, hence
$$ \infty = \limsup \infty = \limsup \mu(E_n) \not\le \mu(\limsup E_n) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$$